# verbose class definition in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-class

I have a class with a destructured constructor parameter:

```js
import * as ē from 'three'

export class cylindricCurve extends ē.Curve {
   #scale: number
   #eqs: ((θ: number) => number)[]
   #rounds: number
   #mainAxis: 'x' | 'y'
   constructor({
      eqs,
      scale = 1,
      rounds = 1,
      mainAxis = null,
   }: {
      eqs: ((θ: number) => number)[]
      scale: number
      rounds?: number
      mainAxis?: 'x' | 'y'
   }) {
      super()
      this.#scale = scale
      this.#eqs = eqs
      this.#rounds = rounds
      this.#mainAxis = mainAxis
   }
```

As you can see, this is incredibly verbose, with every name mentioned FIVE times just to initialize member variables.  I wonder if there is a more concise way to achieve the task.

Comment: Notice that the code is actually defining *two* structures: not just the `class` but also the shape of the options object that the constructor accepts. These do not necessarily need to use the same names.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to prove a negative, but while you can get rid of *one* of them by not destructuring, I think you're stuck with the other ones because you can't auto-declare-and-initialize a private field from a constructor parameter (like you can with TypeScript's `public`, `protected`, and `private` parameter annotations; and even those you'd have to have discrete parameters for rather than destructuring).

Here's that minor change, just for completeness:

```
import * as ē from 'three'

export class cylindricCurve extends ē.Curve {
   #scale: number
   #eqs: ((θ: number) => number)[]
   #rounds: number
   #mainAxis: 'x' | 'y'
   constructor(props: {                         // ***
      eqs: ((θ: number) => number)[]
      scale: number
      rounds?: number
      mainAxis?: 'x' | 'y'
   }) {
      super()
      this.#scale = props.scale ?? 1            // ***
      this.#eqs = props.eqs                     // ***
      this.#rounds = props.rounds ?? 1          // ***
      this.#mainAxis = props.mainAxis ?? null   // ***
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After finding an eight years old issue in TypeScript (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5326), I tried to follow one of the workarounds:

```js
import * as ē from 'three'

export class cylindricCurve extends ē.Curve {
   private scale: number = 1
   private eqs: ((a: number) => number)[]
   private rounds?: number = 1
   private mainAxis?: 'x' | 'y' = null

   constructor(_: cylindricCurve) {
      super()
      Object.assign(this, _)
   }
}
```

While this works, I am not too happy with this approach, which looks unnecessarily hacky, and lacks flexibility: every property now is doomed to be a valid constructor argument.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't mention the `Object.assign` option because A) You were using true JavaScript private fields and it doesn't work with those, and B) It assigns *everything* in the source object, not just the ones you want (which I think is what you mean that end), and (C) you have to use a `!` assertion on the `eqs` member since TypeScript can't see the fact you're definitely assigning it in the constructor. If you're okay with using `private` instead of true private fields, we can deal with (B) like this to get it down to just two copies of each name: https://tsplay.dev/NlzJeW

Comment: Side note: The convention in TypeScript is that using `_` in a parameter name (either on its own or as a prefix) means the parameter is intentionally unused in the function (some linters even automatically exempts them from their warnings). Above you're using it as a parameter name but you're using the parameter, which is unusual. (It's also unusual in TypeScript for a class name not to start with a capitalized letter.)

Comment: "*every property now is doomed to be a valid constructor argument*" - and not just those 4 private properties that you declared, but also all methods of your class and all properties and methods inherited from `three.Curve`.

Comment: [^^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77626391/verbose-class-definition-in-typescript?noredirect=1#comment136860837_77631340) Note that that's true even though `Object.assign` doesn't copy inherited properties...because the shape is just a shape, it would be valid to pass in an object with *own* properties corresponding to inherited ones. And since they'd be own properties, they'd be copied. [Simpler example showing that](https://tsplay.dev/w21b9W).